# laravel 5 redirect route to external url

Tags: laravel-5

I am in the process of moving a website to a new version of the site that has been created to Laravel 5,

However, I need to link to some old static content in a subdirectory on my old site, so I would like to create a route that automatically re-directs any querys to a specific sub-directory to to the old site.

For example:

user goes to:

```
www.site1.com/brochures/brochure1
```

I want it to redirect to:

```
www.oldsite.com/brochures/brochure1
```

And I want to have it do this for anything that comes in as

```
www.site1.com/brochures/whatever  ...
```

I want it to duplicate the same path but redirected to the old site.  I don't want to have to put in each brochure, as every once in a while a new brochure gets added...

Comment: Why not send http request in the controller to that old site and receive data using http requests. By doing you will be completely sifted to this new project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something such as

```
Route::get('/brochures/{brochure}', function($brochure){
    return redirect('http://othersite.com/brochures/'.$brochure);
});
```

Comment: This did exactly what I needed ... I removed the initial / in the get as my other routes did not have an initial / don't know if it makes a difference or not...

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
return redirect()->to($path);
```